# register taxonomy url rewrite 404

Tags: custom-post-types

So here's my code:

```
   register_taxonomy('koolitused', 'koolitus', array('label' => __('Kategooriad', 'Creativo'), 
    'query_var' => true,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    //'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'koolituste_kalender', 'with_front' => true),
    'has_archive'           => true) );


$slug =  'koolitus';

$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Koolitused', 'Post Type General Name', 'Creativo' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Koolitus', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'Creativo' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Koolitused', 'Creativo' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'Creativo' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'Kõik koolitused', 'Creativo' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'Vaata koolitust', 'Creativo' ),
    'view_items'          => __('Vaata koolitusi', 'Creativo'),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Lisa uus koolitus', 'Creativo' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Lisa uus', 'Creativo' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Muuda', 'Creativo' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Uuenda koolitust', 'Creativo' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Otsi koolitust', 'Creativo' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Ei leitud', 'Creativo' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Ei leitud prügikastist', 'Creativo' ),
    'filter_items_list' => _x( 'Koolitus', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'Creativo' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => _x( 'Koolitus', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'Creativo' ),
    'items_list' => _x( 'Koolitus', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'Creativo' ),
    'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Koolitus', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'Creativo' ),
);

$args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'koolitus'),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'can_export' => true,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-book-alt'
    );

register_post_type(
    'koolitus', $args
);
```

The problem is that i can't access the category archive page, it gives me 404.

I tried to flush my permalinks, nothing. I tried looking around in detail, tried all solution but nothing works.

I can access a category, for example:
www.domain.com/koolituste_kalender/category

But i can't access the archive page
www.comain.com/koolituste_kalender
This will give me page nout found aka 404 page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the slug for the post type archive to just `koolitus`, here:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'koolitus'),
```

So it will be accessible at www.domain.com/koolitus

Comment: This will display the post archive, but i want to access the category archive page domain.com/koolituste_kalender

Comment: Sorry, you mean like a list of categories? There's no such thing in WordPress. You would need to do a lot of custom code and templates for that.

Comment: Yeah, like a list of categories. Oh i see, well i'll invent something, thanks for the information.